# Python docx module-Cover Page of the word document

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on an existing word report and trying to do some automation with python docx module. I need to get the report date from database and paste it to "cover page" of the doc but I couldn't find any attribute about cover page in module. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

1. In the word document write any text where you want to replace the date picked from your database eg: dd-mm-yyyy
2. You can now search for your entered text "dd-mm-yy" in the word file using regular expressions and replace it with the Date you got from your database.

   The code will be as follows:

   ```
   def docx_replace_regex(doc_obj,replaceDate):

       regex = re.compile(r"dd-mm-yyyy")

       for p in doc_obj.paragraphs:
           if regex.search(p.text):            
               p.text = regex.sub(replaceDate, p.text)                   


       doc.save('generatedDocument.docx')


   filename = "Your Word Document Path.docx"  
   doc = Document(filename)  
   docx_replace_regex(doc,date)
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, the code starts working from first page of the document. Cover page is not in the scope of the code. İ need to interfere the cover page. In my document there is a table in cover page but when i type doc.table[0], it gets me the table from the first page, not from the cover page.